# Why is my code not displaying the expected texture image?

Tags: c, opengl, sdl

I've created an example of the problem with this program. Please excuse the old style OpenGL. I'm porting a program which relies on legacy code, and this makes the process a bit simpler, for now.

```
#include <SDL_opengl.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define INITIAL_SCREEN_WIDTH 640
#define INITIAL_SCREEN_HEIGHT 480

#define PATTERN_WIDTH  3
#define PATTERN_HEIGHT 3

int screenWidth, screenHeight;

const float quadWidth = 300.0f;
const float quadHeight = 300.0f;

float quadX = (INITIAL_SCREEN_WIDTH / 2) - (quadWidth / 2);
float quadY = (INITIAL_SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2) - (quadHeight / 2);

GLuint texture;

#define RED   0xff0000ff
#define GREEN 0xff00ff00
#define BLUE  0xffff0000

static  unsigned long pattern[] = {
    RED,   GREEN, BLUE,
    GREEN, BLUE,  RED,
    BLUE,  RED,   GREEN
};

void setupOpenGL(int width, int height) {
    screenWidth = width;
    screenHeight = height;

    glViewport(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, INITIAL_SCREEN_WIDTH, INITIAL_SCREEN_HEIGHT, 0, -1, 1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, PATTERN_WIDTH, PATTERN_HEIGHT, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pattern);
}

void drawQuad() {
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0); glVertex2f(quadX, quadY);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0, 0.0); glVertex2f(quadX + quadWidth, quadY);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0, 1.0); glVertex2f(quadX + quadWidth, quadY + quadHeight);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0, 1.0); glVertex2f(quadX, quadY + quadHeight);
    glEnd();

    SDL_GL_SwapWindow(SDL_GL_GetCurrentWindow());
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "SDL could not initialize! SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        return 1;
    }

    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("OpenGL Quad Example", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, INITIAL_SCREEN_WIDTH, INITIAL_SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN | SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE);
    if (!window) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Window could not be created! SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        return 1;
    }

    SDL_GLContext glContext = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);
    if (!glContext) {
        fprintf(stderr, "OpenGL context could not be created! SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        return 1;
    }

    setupOpenGL(INITIAL_SCREEN_WIDTH, INITIAL_SCREEN_HEIGHT);

    int quit = 0;
    while (!quit) {
        SDL_Event event;
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT) {
                quit = 1;
            }
            else if (event.type == SDL_WINDOWEVENT && event.window.event == SDL_WINDOWEVENT_SIZE_CHANGED) {
                int newWidth = event.window.data1;
                int newHeight = event.window.data2;
                setupOpenGL(newWidth, newHeight);
            }
        }

        drawQuad();
    }

    SDL_GL_DeleteContext(glContext);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

I'm compiling it on Ubuntu with this makefile

```
CFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -std=c99
INCLUDES = $(shell pkg-config --cflags sdl2)
LIBS = $(shell pkg-config --libs sdl2) -lGL
OUTPUT = main

SRC = main.c

all: $(OUTPUT)

$(OUTPUT): $(SRC)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -o $(OUTPUT) $(SRC) $(LIBS)

clean:
    rm -f $(OUTPUT)

.PHONY: all clean
```

I expect for it to display a textured quad with a 3x3, RGBA image, as defined in the 'pattern' array. However, instead of the expected pattern, I get the following.

[image]

The top left red texel is correct, but it seems to skip over pixels after that. It occured to me that it might be because the size is not a power of 2, but that doesn't solve the problem. Do you have any idea where I might be going wrong?

Comment: What's `sizeof(unsigned long)` on your platform?  Is it different from `sizeof(uint32_t)`?

Comment: Does switching `pattern[]` from `unsigned long` to `uint32_t` (from `stdint.h`) fix things?

Comment: You've got it. `unsigned long` is 8 bytes here. I assumed it was 4, for some reason. I need to read up more on my assumptions about data type sizes in C. Thank you, that's fixed.

Comment: @denormal `unsigned long` is always 32 bits wide on MS Windows. On Linux, `unsigned long` could be 32 or 64 bits wide and is always the same size as a pointer.